# Creating inputs that depend on each other with Shiny and Flexdashboard

Tags: r, shiny, flexdashboard

I have tried creating a drop-down that depends on a different widget ID.

In this app, the symbol drop-down-list depends on the input from the Stock Class chckboxGroupButtons()

I've successfully implemented that, but after inserting an eventReactive () that delays the reactive filtering and only starts filtering once "apply" is selected, the app shows an empty dataframe to start with.

Only AFTER clicking on either "Apply" or "Reset" then the app works the way it should.

I just need the unfiltered dataframe when rendering the app for the first time.

How do I fix this?

Code:

```
---
title: "Sample App"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
runtime: shiny
---
```

```
library(flexdashboard)
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinyjs)

# Core
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
```

```
# Make data
symbols        <- purrr::cross_df(list(numbers = 1:90,letters = LETTERS))

symbols$symbol <-  paste(symbols$numbers,symbols$letters,sep = " - ")

set.seed(123)
stock_prices_tbl <- tibble(
  date  = seq.Date(from = ymd("2018-01-01"), to = Sys.Date(), length.out = 90),
  class = sample(c("marketing", "sales", "research"), size = 90, replace = TRUE),
  symbol = sample(symbols$symbol,size = 90,replace = F),
  adjusted = runif(n = 90,min = 0,90)
  )
```

```
Sidebar {.sidebar}
---
```

```
# Allow shiny js
shinyjs::useShinyjs(rmd = T)

dateRangeInput(
inputId   = "date_range", 
label     = h4("Date Range"),
start     = min(stock_prices_tbl$date),
end       = max(stock_prices_tbl$date),
min       = min(stock_prices_tbl$date),
max       = max(stock_prices_tbl$date),
startview = "month")

shinyWidgets::checkboxGroupButtons(
  inputId   = "class", 
  label     = h4("Stock Class"), 
  choices   = unique(stock_prices_tbl$class), 
  selected  = unique(stock_prices_tbl$class), 
  checkIcon = list(
    yes = icon("ok", lib = "glyphicon"),
    no  = icon("remove", lib = "glyphicon")
  ))



 shiny::renderUI({

    shinyWidgets::pickerInput(
inputId   = "symbol",label = h4("Symbol"),
choices   = unique(stock_prices_tbl[stock_prices_tbl$class %in% input$class,]$symbol),
selected  = unique(stock_prices_tbl[stock_prices_tbl$class %in% input$class,]$symbol),
multiple  = TRUE,
options   = list(
`actions-box`          = TRUE,
size                   = 10,
`selected-text-format` = "count",
`live-search`          = TRUE

))

})

br()
hr()
br()

shiny::actionButton(inputId = "apply",label = "Apply",icon = shiny::icon("play"))



# Resetting app to default values:
actionButton(inputId = "reset", label = "Reset", icon = shiny::icon("sync"))

observeEvent(eventExpr = input$reset, handlerExpr = {

  updateCheckboxGroupButtons(
    session  = session, 
    inputId  = "class", 
    selected = unique(stock_prices_tbl$class))

  updatePickerInput(
    session = session, 
    inputId = "symbol", 
    selected = unique(stock_prices_tbl$symbol))

  updateDateRangeInput(
    session = session, 
    inputId = "date_range", 
    start   = min(stock_prices_tbl$date), 
    end     = max(stock_prices_tbl$date))


# We'll need to mimic a click when resetting our app to defaults
shinyjs::delay(ms = 300,expr = {shinyjs::click(
id = "apply" # The input id that you want to enforce when resetting to defaults
              )

})


})
```

```
# Delay Reactions

stocks_reactive <- shiny::eventReactive(eventExpr = input$apply ,valueExpr = {

    stock_prices_tbl %>%
        filter(
            between(date,input$date_range[1],input$date_range[2]) &
                class %in% input$class & 
                symbol %in% input$symbol

               )

},ignoreNULL = F, ignoreInit = F)
```

```
Column {data-width=1000}
---
```

```
renderPrint(expr = {stocks_reactive()})
```